# words pair count pair should be in paragraph boundaries

Tags: hadoop

Help needed in words pair count, pair should be in paragraph boundaries. For example Previous word should not be last word of a paragraph in text file and next word should not be first word of new paragraph in a word count pair.  could you please get me an idea how can I implement in Hadoop(frame work) using Java

Answer (score 0):

please explain better what you need and what the scenario is. if i understand correctly you will want your map reduce job to process the text paragraph by paragraph, implement in the mapper your desired logic (what you specified with prev word/next word), and in the reducer implement the usual summing reduce() function